# Understanding word alignment

Tags: algorithm, hardware, theory, cpu-architecture

I understand what it means to access memory such that it is aligned but I don’t understand why this is necessary. For instance, why can I access a single byte from an address `0x…1` but I cannot access a half word (two bytes) from the same address.

Again, I understand that if you have an address `A` and an object of size `s` that the access is aligned if `A mod s = 0`. But I just don’t understand why this is important at the hardware level.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*Hardware is complex; this is a simplified explanation.*

A typical modern computer might have a 32-bit data bus. This means that any fetch that the CPU needs to do will fetch all 32 bits of a particular memory address. Since the data bus can't fetch anything smaller than 32 bits, the lowest two address bits aren't even used on the address bus, so it's as if RAM is organised into a sequence of 32-bit *words* instead of 8-bit *bytes*.

When the CPU does a fetch for a single byte, the read cycle on the bus will fetch 32 bits and then the CPU will discard 24 of those bits, loading the remaining 8 bits into whatever register. If the CPU wants to fetch a 32 bit value that is *not* aligned on a 32-bit boundary, it has several general choices:

- execute two separate read cycles on the bus to load the appropriate parts of the data word and reassemble them
- read the 32-bit word at the address determined by throwing away the low two bits of the address
- read some unexpected combination of bytes assembled into a 32-bit word, probably not the one you wanted
- throw an exception

Various CPUs I have worked with have taken all four of those paths. In general, for maximum compatibility it is safest to align all n-bit reads to an n-bit boundary. However, you can certainly take shortcuts if you are sure that your software will run on some particular CPU family with known unaligned read behaviour. And even if unaligned reads are possible (such as on x86 family CPUs), they will be slower.

Comment: *the lowest two address bits aren't even used on the address bus* If so then how 32 bit address is addressed with just 30 bit? Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: yeah that part needs clarification. He mentions the lowest two bits twice. In the second solution it sounds like he can do one read instead of two, which also doesn't make sense since we said that it's not aligned.

Comment: isn't it the least-significant 5 bits that have to be set to 0

Comment: Can anyone clarify why lowest 2 bits are not used here?

Answer (score 13):

The computer always reads in some fixed size chunks which are aligned.

So, if you don't align your data in memory, you will have to probably read more than once.

**Example**

- word size is 8 bytes
- your structure is also 8 bytes
- if you align it, you'll have to read one chunk
- if you don't align it, you'll have to read two chunks

So, it's basically to speed up.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for *all* alignment rules are the various widths of the Cache Lines (Instruction-Cache do have 16 Byte lines for the Core2 Architecture, and the Data-Cache do have 64-Byte Lines for L1 and 128-Byte Lines for L2).

So if you want to store/load data that crosses a Cahce-Line Boundary you need to load and store both Cache-lines, which hits the performance.
So you just don't do it because of the performance hit, its that simple.

Comment: could you elaborate your answer more? it sounds interesting. modern processors rarely address memory directly. what they actual fetch data from is cache. so word alignment should have something to do with cache only?  many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try reading a serial port. The data is 8 bits wide.
Nice hardware designers ensure it lies on a least significant byte of the word.

If you have a C structure that has elements not word aligned ( from backwards compatibility or  conservation of memory say )
then the address of any byte within the structure is not word aligned.